# Purposefully Maxing out Memory on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, server, performance-monitor

I'm looking into using Windows Performance Monitor to analyse server performance. I'm testing on the adventure works 2014 database on SQL Server 2014.

I want to try to Max out the CPU, Memory, disk usage (I/O) and possibly put a high amount of User activity. Then I can train myself in using windows performance monitor to take logs for performances around this area.

I know for CPU I can just run a heavy query within a while loop (maybe infinite) and that will go towards maxing it out.

I'm less sure about the other ones. I've tried queries which select from large tables (30,000 records), and are in a while loop to try and use some of the memory up. But it doesn't seem to drop the Available Mbytes left counter on performance monitor. Is this because the tables not big enough?

As for the disk usage, I imagine I may have to do some updates or inserts so that the disk is being written to. But I can't seem to get it to effect disk usage.

As for network, I can only think of opening up multiple queries and running them concurrently, but that seems a bit messy.

As a side note, I want to script it all myself. Rather than using any extra tools or pre canned apps that do it for you.

Comment: For disk, take a look at the DiskSpd tool https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223 & tips here https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/09/getting-started-with-diskspd/ Regarding memory, SQL will use as much as you allow it to (what's your Max Memory setting & how much total RAM does the server have?), but should release some back to the OS if/when it's requested. So Available MBytes may not be a useful metric. In general, there are SQL-specific performance counters which you will probably find much more useful than generic server-level CPU/RAM/disk.

Comment: I'm looking to specifically use those counters rather than the sql specific ones. Im working from the base up really. I forgot to mention that I don't want to use any tools. Just write scripts to do it, if possible.

Comment: SQL server does not seem to drop memory once allocated until it is restarted. I suppose you can still cause current memory utilization to go up by using the cursors with large data. Perhaps use `varchar(max)` fields populated with lots of data, or XML fields. Write something crazy complex, like queries with joins based on XPath.